# Stop MAMP MySQL

Tags: mysql, mamp, kill

How do you end all MySQL processes?  Or how to address this error?  MAMP won't start the MySQL server.

```
120805 11:18:24 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
120805 11:18:24 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 8889 ?
120805 11:18:24 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Killed process in Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 14):

You can shut Mysql down using the following command:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/stopMysql.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit the second line of MAMP/bin/start.sh by adding an initial # ...

```
# /bin/sh
#/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh
/Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh
```

then when MAMP starts, MySQL will not, only Apache.

Comment: Editing `MAMP/bin/start.sh` did not work for me. Instead, I have commented out the launch of mysql in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I reckon MAMP installs mysql properly, so you can to `mysql.server stop` to stop all instances of the server. Same goes for `mysql.server start` to start it again.